# Dependent Props on React with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have made a Button React Component:

```
function Button({ text, Icon, iconProps, ...buttonProps }: ButtonProps)
```

The props must have this structure:

- Only a `text`
- Only an `Icon`
- An `Icon` with `iconProps` (the `iconProps` can only be passed if the `Icon` is also present)
- A `text`, an `Icon`
- A `text`, an `Icon` and `iconProps`
- It cannot be empty, it has to either have at least a `text` or an `Icon`

If I make all the props optional I loose the type safety I am aiming to. I've attempted to create an interface for each scenario and make a union of all of them, but it is not working and doesn't seem like an elegant minimalistic solution:

```
interface ButtonOnlyText extends React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
  text: string;
}

interface ButtonOnlyIcon extends React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
  Icon: React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
}

interface ButtonIconWithProps extends React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
  Icon: React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
  iconProps: React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>;
}

interface ButtonTextAndIcon extends React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
  text: string;
  Icon: React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
}

interface ButtonComplete extends React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
  text: string;
  Icon: React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
  iconProps: React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>;
}

type ButtonProps = ButtonOnlyText | ButtonOnlyIcon | ButtonIconWithProps | ButtonTextAndIcon | ButtonComplete

declare function Button({ text, Icon, iconProps, ...buttonProps }: ButtonProps): React.FC;
```

This is the [link to Typescript playground with the code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=29&ssc=91&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgCEBXGGCageWoBsAngBUkAD3ji61ACYBnRMRgA6dp24AJYQFkAMgEFOUYACMOSOQB4tetV2oBRfkhBJaAPjgBvcnDh0JAC44ORhjagBzCgBfSho6BiZWDns%20IQBJNG44KTd5RXQVO00dAyNTcysbXWLHZ1cPb184TO5g5ELlADE2agxgbgBhXEhqNxhLDoxlAGUANQBxAAUcMCt5hY2nF3H3dxi42npGNGZa1uoAdWAYAAsViDWciTyFKaKUkr1DMIq6KtKtW2DRgnh8fgu7SU3V6-SGI2440m0I2DzWlg2W3qu32zWAWWoaLkUM6qNW60WWJ2HgOVCOiVOyXU1FEEn0sguz2k%20Xeqk%201GqP2MZn%201kB-OBuyafgCMGCoXCUWakIK0x6fRgA2ow3AiNoyNJiyJGMpi0lHlxsTpCROZ35OrAzjoXNeqo%20zMF5RFFjFtgl2Ma4P8Unlv0iFAhBJJathmvhurG%20t5ZMeFM2ZoDoNxfnx3CJ0ZUKfRmIz1NBtJggjAduZRLgAF4makBCIpHAAD5N7hpQSczvnAnXO51-v81kwdkyPtd7UjJ1ISgyJBofgoIhwTCxrUzgAUXmDEgANC0Ccfc4TycflNeRfY69FgrUiQBKAvdQakIA) for seeing the error.

Comment: You've made a set of possible cases. Some can be slightly collapsed/merged. What is the problem you're facing with this solution specifically?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you destructure on a `declare function`. Is it just for the post? You couldn't destructure this way anyway, since you can't know ahead of time which prop will or won't be there

Comment: Hi @Vivick. I have edited the question with a link to the code where you can see the error I am facing which says that none of the props exists on `ButtonProps`. I have used `declare function` for this post so that everyone can try to test the code. What do you mean by "some can be slightly collapsed/merged"?

Comment: Like vivek said, you can't know ahead of time which props are present. You need to check if text is present before you can extract it for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My experience trying to make this kind of complicated types is that it rarely ends well, it almost always ends up with types that are pretty difficult to use, so I would instead try to simplify things.

It seems like you have two different problems you want to solve:

- at least one of text and icon should be present
- iconProps should only be present when Icon is present

For the first problem, I'm not sure how important it actually is. The users of your Button component will end up with a weird-looking empty button, which they will surely notice pretty quickly and fix by adding either a text or an icon (or both). So I would simply ignore this problem and make both optional.

For the second problem, instead of expecting a React component as the icon, you could accept instead some arbitrary JSX:

```js
// Before
<Button Icon={MyIcon} iconProps={{someProp: value}} />

// After
<Button icon={<MyIcon someProp={value}/>} />
```

This way you simply need to accept a prop `icon?: ReactNode` and you don't need to care about `iconProps` at all. It is up to the caller to pass the right JSX.

You could even go one step further and simply accept `children: ReactNode` instead of both `text` and `icon`, which gives even more flexibility to the users of this component. Maybe someone wants to put the icon on the other side, or have two icons, or have a png icon, or have some bold text, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Guillaume Brunerie, I liked the way you approached the solution for this problem!

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce your set of interfaces as `{ a: A; } | { a: A; b: B; }` is `{ a: A; b?: B; }`:

```
interface ButtonOnlyText extends React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
  text: string;
}

interface ButtonOnlyIcon extends React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
  Icon: React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
  iconProps?: React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>;
}

interface ButtonTextAndIcon extends React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> {
  text: string;
  Icon: React.FunctionComponent<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
  iconProps?: React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>;
}
```

Then you can't declare `Button` as

```
function Button({ text, Icon, iconProps, ...buttonProps }: ButtonProps)
```

Simply because there are interfaces in your disjunction that don't have the props you're trying to access. Typescript will tell you that these properties are not defined.

All you can do is declare it as

```
function Button(props: ButtonProps)
```

And then have some code that'd work like this:

```
const buttonProps = restrict(props).toAllBut(["text", "Icon", "iconProps"]);
```

And query for the props you want to access like this:

```
if ("text" in props && "Icon" in props) // ButtonTextAndIcon
```

And handle all cases as you please.

You might want to expose these components instead:

```
declare function TextButton({ text, ...buttonAttributes }: ButtonOnlyText): React.FC;
declare function IconButton({ Icon, iconProps, ...buttonAttributes }: ButtonOnlyIcon): React.FC;
declare function TextIconButton({ text, Icon, iconProps, ...buttonAttributes }: ButtonTextAndIcon): React.FC;
```

That all delegate to the main `Button`.

Comment: Thanks @Vivick, I know understand why it was incorrect to destructure the props on the function declaration. I am rather new with React and Typescript and I don't know if it is worth going through the trouble of defining all this types for handling the dependant properties of a component. Is it actually a good practice to do so or should I just stick with marking all the props as optional?

Comment: You have better DX when you can clearly see what your options are VS when everything's optional. Then again, you could also make a base component, and 3 variant components (text only, icon only, text icon)

Comment: Really appreciate all your input, thanks @Vivick!!